# Convert excel formula to linux bash script

Tags: excel, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to convert the following excel-formula into a simple bash script:

```
=IF(B3*10>B5,1,IF(TRUNC(B5/B3/10)>3,3,TRUNC(B5/B3/10)))
```

Examples:

- If B3="2" and B5="39"; the output ("VAL") should be 1
- If B3="2" and B5="40"; the output ("VAL") should be 2
- If B3="2" and B5="60"; the output ("VAL") should be 3

This is what I've tried, but the output is not correct:

```
if (( $B3 \* 10 > $B5 )); then
if (( $B5 \/ $B3 \/ 10 > 3 )); then
VAL="3"
else
VAL=`expr $B5 \/ $B3 \/ 10`
fi fi
```

Where is the error? :)

Comment: "the output is not correct" what is the output you are getting vs. what is expected?

Comment: When B3="2" and B5="40"; the expected output ("VAL") should be 2.
Instead; $VAL is empty.

Comment: `((...))` is the shell's arithmetic expression syntax. It expects to see arithmetic operators within. Don't escape them.

Comment: Instead of calling out to expr, use the `$((...))` syntax to evaluate the expression, and assign the result to the variable.

Comment: Put your `fi`s on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're not setting VAL to 1 in the first "true" branch.

```sh
if (( B3 * 10 > B5 )); then
  VAL=1
elif (( B5 / B3 / 10 > 3 )); then
  VAL=3
else
  VAL=$((B5 / B3 / 10))
fi
```

bash lets you refer to variables without the `$` inside an arithmetic expression.

Testing:

```sh
B3=2
for B5 in 10 39 40 60 80; do
  if (( B3 * 10 > B5 )); then
    branch="first"
    VAL=1
  elif (( B5 / B3 / 10 > 3 )); then
    branch="second"
    VAL=3
  else
    branch="third"
    VAL=$((B5 / B3 / 10))
  fi
  echo "$B3 $B5 $VAL $branch"
done
```

```
2 10 1 first
2 39 1 third
2 40 2 third
2 60 3 third
2 80 3 second
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, this looks promising! :) I will try it out first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Note that bash only does _integer_ arithmetic, so `79/2/10` is `3`